# What to do with black-screen tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

I just came across the [black-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/black-screen) tag that has about 81 questions tagged against it. A quick look at the questions seem to suggest that they are either graphic problems or boot error. I am not sure what we should do with the tag. So, I thought I would start a meta post to discuss the matter.

**Update**: 95 questions have been tagged with this. We should do something about this already!

Comment: Why do anything? It is a common Linux problem that people are looking for an answer for. Perhaps, as suggested elsewhere, there should be a canonical question/answer for black-screen issues. In that case, perhaps the tag could be removed and the existing questions re-tagged.

Comment: This may be the solution: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3665/lets-consolidate-black-screen-on-boot-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burned and blacklisted - both [black](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/black) and [black-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/black-screen).

Please care for [the widows and orphans](https://askubuntu.com/tags/untagged).

Comment: *Adds to todo.txt*

Answer (score 5):

Trogdor! We need your assistance!

[image]

Comment: He's not a mod anymore :(

Answer (score 3):

Kill it! We kill it and forget about it! Do it fast, do it clean, just like [Dexter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_%28TV_series%29) would!