# Let's consolidate "black screen on boot" questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

We have 858 questions about this, it's probably time to consolidate this into one good CW and start duping things instead of having it all over the site, so we made this:

- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Discussions/ideas can go in this meta post.

Comment: I don't really care *how* we do it, but I've got 1K rep to offer in bounties for this.

Comment: This is one of those times where I wish you could bounty a CW and have the rep just dish out to each contributor.

Comment: @jrg, Jorge Yeah, every time there's a quest for a reference answer I wish this was possible. [Awarding a bounty to an editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89387)

Answer (score 8):

From all the questions about black screen issues, I was surprised they most had different causes and different solutions! I did not find any that matched my problem.

Comment: Right, that's why we're putting them in one place instead of spread all over the site.

Comment: @August Guillaume  What was the problem that you were experiencing?